# The instance of entity type 'Entity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a method that proceses a query and deletes the rows from the table.

But every time I get the following error:
`The instance of entity type 'NotificationQueueEntry' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.`

This is the whole method:

```
    public static void ProcessQueue()
    {
        var query = _dbContext.Notifications
            .Where(x => x.TransferInterval == TransferIntervalEnum.Instant);
        
        var notificationsToProcess = query.ToList();

        _dbContext.Notifications.RemoveRange(query);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        
        if (!notificationsToProcess.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var queue = notificationsToProcess.Select(notification => new MailRequest
        {
            Id = notification.Id,
            MailType = Smtp.MailTypeEnum.HTML,
            MailMessage = new MailMessage
            {
                content = notification.Content.content,
                from = SmtpConfiguration.From, subject = notification.Content.subject,
                to = notification.TransferIdentifier
            }
        }).ToList();

        Smtp.ProcessItems(queue, SmtpConfiguration);
        
    }
```

The error is in this line `_dbContext.Notifications.RemoveRange(query);`

How can I solve this? I need to have the `notificationsToProcess` variable as well..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a linq expression to select a list of IDs you can use for items in query, and then maybe delete/save the notifications after your processing is complete